# How to fix the number and length of vectors when using ListVectorPLot

Tags: vector

I want to plot only the vectors that I specify in my list of vectors, and no more. ListVectorPlot plots many of them, namely plots the field extrapolating from my four vectors.I would also like to have the length I give them, that is, if my list is the following:

```
list = {{{-1, -1},{2, -2}}, {{1, -1},{2, 2}}, {{1, 1},{-2,2}}, {{-1, 1},{-2,-2}}};
```

I would like to have just four vectors at sites {-1,-1},{1,-1},{1,1} and {-1,1} of length `Sqrt[2²+2²]`.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Like `Graphics[Arrow /@ {{{-1, -1}, {2, -2}}, {{1, -1}, {2, 2}}, {{1, 1}, {-2, 2}}, {{-1, 1}, {-2, -2}}}]`?

Comment: @J.M. this does not give the right angle of the vectors though. For example, I would like {2,2} to have 45º or {-2,-2} 225º and so on...Is this possible?

Comment: Like putting an origin of the vectors in each position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Result after many comments and questions:

```
 Graphics[Arrow[{#1, #1 + #2} & @@@ list]]
```

[image]

Comment: Lenght can have the value You need. That is what I've understood Mencia wants.

Comment: @Kuba this does not give the right angle of the vectors though. For example, I would like {2,2} to have 45º or {-2,-2} 225º and so on...Like putting an origin at each position.

Comment: So You don want vectors from Your list, You want vectors with origin in {0,0}?

Comment: Given my list, I would like to have for origins at positions {1,1},{-1,1},{-1,-1} and {1,-1}, from which I plot the corresponding four vectors.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now. Look at the picture and tell me if I do :)

Comment: @Kuba, yeah, that is perfect! But if I do not want all of them to have the same length, for example if my four vectors are {2,1}, {3,2},{1,1} and {-1,3}, being a vector {a,b}, I want it to have length Sqrt[a²+b²]?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8971/discussion-between-kuba-and-mencia)

Comment: if you do Graphics[{Arrowheads[Norm@#2/0.000001], Arrow[{#1, #1 + #2}]} & @@@ 
  list] you will see that there is a tiny cross at each of the positions specified at list. How can I get rid of these crosses? I only want the arrows in my plot. Thanks.

Comment: where list={{{-1, -1}, {2.1*10^-8, -2.1*10^-8}}, {{1, -1}, {2.1*10^-8, 
   2.1*10^-8}}, {{1, 1}, {-2.1*10^-8, 2.1*10^-8}}, {{-1, 
   1}, {-2.1*10^-8, -2.1*10^-8}}}